# Where can I find examples of down-range launch exclusion zones for Falcon-9 and Antares orbital launches?

Tags: falcon-9, antares, range-safety

I generally understand the concept of the LDZ, but would like to look at actual examples for past Falcon and Antares orbital launches. How are private boaters and the general public warned about KSC/Canaveral launches and the corresponding downrange exclusion zones?  Is there a link to public notices and Notice to Mariners/Airmen from past launches at KSC and Wallops?

Comment: I'm still learning how this goes exactly for all US spaceports but for KSC they are published by [45th Space Wing at Patrick AFB](http://www.patrick.af.mil/) (examples for SpaceX Orbcomm OG-2 launch: [Launch Hazard Area](http://www.patrick.af.mil/shared/media/document/AFD-151219-003.pdf), [Airspace Closure Area](http://www.patrick.af.mil/shared/media/document/AFD-151219-004.pdf)). Authorities would be USAF / USSTRATCOM and COMSTAC / FAA for orbital and airspace, and USCG and MARAD for maritime exclusion zones. Ground, when it extends beyond spaceport range, is probably US Army and USMS.

Comment: FAA? https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/notices/ for archived versions? They pulled off HTML versions from the site this April.

Answer (score 2):

The marine zones *should* be in the USCG local notice to mariners
http://www.navcen.uscg.gov/pdf/lnms/lnm11012017.pdf
(that doesn't have an example, but it should...)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [example from a June 2018 (planned) launch](https://www.navcen.uscg.gov/pdf/lnms/lnm07222018.pdf) of Falcon 9. [See page 9](https://www.navcen.uscg.gov/pdf/lnms/lnm07222018.pdf).

[image]

Googling for the two phrases:

"Local Notice to Mariners"  "Eastern Range"

is an effective way to find Florida launches.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.navcen.uscg.gov/chart

> Space Operations Launch and Recovery (SOLAR) Chart
>
> Space Launch and Recovery Operations will be conducted within portions of the Warning Areas and Hazard Areas displayed on the chart below, and may include free falling debris and/or descending vehicles or vehicle components under various means of control. Mariners are urged to avoid waters within these areas during launch windows. For more information, mariners may contact the U.S. Space Force Launch Information hotline at 1-800-470-7232. Click HERE for the reference guide. (Data accurate as of: 08 DEC 2023 1755 Z.) (You are in mobile mode: use 1 finger to scroll the page and two fingers to move the map.)